# Enable remote desktop on fedora 20 kde

Tags: remote-access, kde, fedora-20

I have a remote Fedora-20 kde 4.12.3 system and I can ssh into it no problem. I would however like to use the GUI for various purposes. Is there an option to enable to let me log into the linux machine using remote desktop? Also is there an ssh way of enabling? Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The best solution I could find was xrdp. Its simple, easy and works really well. All I had to do was install it, open firewall rules for it. I was in business soon after! Thanks for the help Richie!

---

This was the procedure I followed:

> su -
>
> yum install xrdp

Once this is done, you must configure the firewall rule that will let you use the RDP (Default is 3389).
Check if the port is open and xrdp is listening on it

> netstat -an |grep 3389

If it is, you are all set and can connect anytime. If not, open the firewall port that is required.

> firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3389/tcp --permanent
>   firewall-cmd --reload

*Note: Decide permanent or temporary based on your need.*

You are all set to connect in. Use IP of your Fedora machine or unique DNS name.

More on xrdp [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/xrdp)

[firewall-cmd basics](http://liquidat.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/howto-firewalld-basics/)

Too little rep points for extra link so please use google for firewall-cmd man page :)

Comment: Where did you find it? How did you set it up? This answer is very low in quality, and may not help future visitors, as is. Please [edit] your answer to include more details. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I would give teamviewer a look.   It allows you connect to any Linux, Windows or Mac OS X box anywhere in the world using a GUI.

http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx

Best of all, its free.